# Where can I find patch notes for every Disagea 4 patch?

Tags: ps3, disgaea-4

There's got to be some resource with listings for: patch number, release date, change notes, right?

Answer (score 1):

On your PS3 go to Game Utility > Disgaea 4 > press triangle and the info you are looking for should appear

Comment: Almost, but not quite. Only the latest patch's factoids are provided there, without any notes detailing what tweaks were made; ie: what did they fix? what did they improve? what did the take away?

Comment: ah sorry i couldn't actually provide an answer to that as i don't think its listed on the website where it actually should...sry